# Why does otftotfm report "No such file or directory"?

Tags: otftotfm

Hi try to run otftotfm on my machine to convert a font. The exact same command I use worked in the past without a problem, but calling it now results in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\otftotfm.exe: temporary file '/tmp/otftotfm.qGxrJ1': No such file or directory`

No pfb, tfm or enc files are created, but otftotfm also does not report an error.

This is on Win10 and I would like to know, how to fix it.

Comment: do you have a `c:\tmp` folder?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No I had not and it seems adding this folder did the trick. It is strange, because using the binaries from mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/lcdf-typetools-w32.tar.xz still works without that folder, but using the ones coming with MikTeX I get stuck here.